# Editing html input field values in javascript does not trigger on.('change', ....) function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dblclick listener that adds values into an html input field. I also have an on change function that is supposed to enable a submit button when the value in that html input field changes. However, sblclicking, and therefore adding a value into the input field, does not enable the submit button. The button does become enabled if I click in the input field and edit the value by hand, though.

Is there a work around so that the dblclick listener can also trigger the on change function?

```js
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    document.getElementById("name").value = "Hello World!";
});

document.getElementById("name").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text">
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Comment: note: you do have to click off of the input field to get the submit button to enable, if you are editing the input field by hand!!

Comment: It's not supposed to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this ...

```js
document.getElementById("name").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
}

document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    document.getElementById("name").value = "Hello World!";
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
        document.getElementById("name").dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("name").fireEvent("onchange");
});
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text">
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing input values dynamically needs explicit event generation.

`var el = document.getElementById('name')
  el.value = 'something';
  el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

[Jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/kogaboriqe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an event to dispatch on the element on document `dblclick`. Also use `oninput` instead of `onchange` like the following way:

```js
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
  document.getElementById("name").value = "Hello World!";

  var event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent('input', true, true);
  document.getElementById("name").dispatchEvent(event);
});

document.getElementById("name").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text">
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the `onchange` method to your initial function?

For example:

```
     document.getElementById("name").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
}

document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    document.getElementById("name").value = "Hello World!";
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
        document.getElementById("name").dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("name").fireEvent("onchange");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally properties modified by javascript do not trigger html change events.

So what you can do is call the code that activates your button from the change handler and the doubleclick handler.  If the code was more complex you could wrap it in a function and call it from both handlers.

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    document.getElementById("name").value = "Hello World!";
    document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
});

document.getElementById("name").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `oninput` instead of `change`

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  document.getElementById("name").value = "Hello World!";
});
document.getElementById("name").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("send").disabled = false;
}


<input id="name" type="text">
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Submit" disabled>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zx8c65sq/1/) here